# R: looping to save multiple shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal, ncdf4

When I try to use writeOGR, plus a loop, to save my shapefiles, it doesn't do anything but give me an error message:

> Error in writeOGR(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT, dsn, layer1, driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : layer exists, use a new layer name

Essentially, I am converting each object into a CSV file, then into a shapefile, and want to save both the CSV files and the shapefiles.  Here is my code fragment:

```
for (m in 1:500){
#First I want to save my CSV files:
drought.slice <- rotate(drought.array[m,,])
drought.vec <- as.vector(drought.slice)
length(drought.vec)
drought.df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, drought.vec))
names(drought.df01) <- c("lon", "lat", paste(dname, as.character(m), sep = "_"))
head(na.omit(drought.df01))
csvfile<-paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv")

#Next I want to create shapefiles from the CSV files:
plot.locations_DROUGHT <- read.csv(paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(plot.locations_DROUGHT[,1:2], plot.locations_DROUGHT)
proj4string(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
dsn <- layer1 <- gsub(".csv","cru_drought_",m)
writeOGR(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT, dsn, layer1, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
}
```

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
    #Open and read the NCDF file, along with longitude and latitude
rm(list=ls())
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
library(chron)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)
setwd('/Users/Neil/Dropbox/Drought Maps')
ncname <- "owda-orig"
ncfname <- paste(ncname,".nc",sep="")
dname <- "pdsi"
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)

lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lat", verbose = F)
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)

print(c(nlon, nlat))

t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
nt <- dim(t)
head(t)

drought.array <- ncvar_get(ncin, dname)
dlname <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname, "long_name")
dunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname, "units")
#fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname, "_FillValue")
dim(drought.array)

creation_date <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "creation_date")
Description <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "Description")

nc_close(ncin)



rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, c(1, 2), rev))

m <- 333
drought.slice <- rotate(drought.array[m,,])
image(lon, lat, drought.slice, col = brewer.pal(10, "BrBG"))

lonlat <- expand.grid(lon, lat)
drought.vec <- as.vector(drought.slice)
length(drought.vec)

drought.df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, drought.vec))
names(drought.df01) <- c("lon", "lat", paste(dname, as.character(m), sep = "_"))
head(na.omit(drought.df01))


for (m in 1:500){
    drought.slice <- rotate(drought.array[m,,])
    drought.vec <- as.vector(drought.slice)
    length(drought.vec)
    drought.df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, drought.vec))
    names(drought.df01) <- c("lon", "lat", paste(dname,         as.character(m), sep = "_"))
    head(na.omit(drought.df01))
    csvfile<-paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv")
    plot.locations_DROUGHT <- read.csv(paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(plot.locations_DROUGHT[,1:2], plot.locations_DROUGHT)
    proj4string(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
    dsn <- layer1 <- gsub(".csv","cru_drought_",m)
    writeOGR(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT, dsn, layer1, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
}
```

Help would be most appreciated.  I'm probably doing something very silly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is in the line where you make the shapefile name. Using `gsub(".csv","cru_drought_",m)` would replace ".csv" with "cru_drought_" in the string `m`, which is just the integer you're looping over. That string isn't found, so it just assigns the integer `m` to `dsn`, so you end up trying to write shapefiles with names like "1", "2", etc. I think you just have the `gsub` arguments kinda scrambled.

I commented out the parts of your code that are specific to your files, and tried to just put together the file names that seem like what you're after.

```r
for (m in 1:5){
    # drought.slice <- rotate(drought.array[m,,])
    # drought.vec <- as.vector(drought.slice)
    # length(drought.vec)
    # drought.df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, drought.vec))
    # names(drought.df01) <- c("lon", "lat", paste(dname,         as.character(m), sep = "_"))
    # head(na.omit(drought.df01))
    csvfile<-paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv")
    # plot.locations_DROUGHT <- read.csv(paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    # plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(plot.locations_DROUGHT[,1:2], plot.locations_DROUGHT)
    # proj4string(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
    dsn <- layer1 <- gsub(".csv","_shape",csvfile)
    # writeOGR(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT, dsn, layer1, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
    print(dsn)
}
#> [1] "cru_drought_1_shape"
#> [1] "cru_drought_2_shape"
#> [1] "cru_drought_3_shape"
#> [1] "cru_drought_4_shape"
#> [1] "cru_drought_5_shape"
```

Created on 2018-04-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you ever so much, this works! 

I have another question: it seems that this process creates separate folders for each shapefile.  Is there a way to simply do this and just save the shapefiles in the working directory folder?

Comment: The `dsn` argument to `writeOGR` is the directory where you're saving the shapefile. Try changing to something like `writeOGR(shapefile, "folder_of_shapes", layer1, driver="ESRI Shapefile")`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit easier to use `raster::shapefile` instead of `writeOGR`

```
shapefile(plot.locationsSP_DROUGHT, dsn)
```